# Airdrop contract not working -- VM error: revert

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I am trying to implement this Airdrop: https://github.com/odemio/airdropper/blob/master/Airdropper.sol
Initially, I started writing tests for our use-case, but the airdrop was not working.

```
function airdrop(address source, address[] dests, uint[] values) public onlyOwner {
    // This simple validation will catch most mistakes without consuming
    // too much gas.
    require(dests.length == values.length);

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < dests.length; i++) {
        require(token.transferFrom(source, dests[i], values[i].mul(multiplier)));
    }
}
```

Then I moved to Remix to go through the whole airdrop process, including our Contract deployment, token minting and allowance.

In Remix debugger I found out that the issue is on the line
`require(token.transferFrom(source, dests[i], values[i].mul(multiplier)));`

I also tested the transferFrom function directly on our contract using the same values on Remix.

The error I get when trying to airdrop is:

> transact to Airdrop.airdrop errored: VM error: revert.
> revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value. Debug the transaction to get more information.

What could cause this issue and how can I debug this further?

Comment: Your post says you went through the process “including allowance”. The `allowance` and `approve` functions are two different things. Did you `approve` your airdrop contract to distribute the tokens?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for misunderstanding - with allowance I meant to say that I have approved the token distribution from another address. :)

Comment: The error could be for several reasons. 1) `source` doesn’t have enough tokens to cover all of the transfers. 2) One or more destination addresses are invalid. 3) The `approve` wasn’t done correctly (it’s the airdrop contract that needs to be approved, not the initiator of the transaction). You can narrow it down by removing the `require` and see if any drops are successful (the way you have it coded, one failure will roll back the entire transaction).

Comment: Hey @AdamKipnis The 3rd option was the correct one! I was approving the contractOwner not the contract itself. Please add this as an anser, so I can approve it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error could be for several reasons:

1. `source` doesn’t have enough tokens to cover all of the transfers.
2. One or more destination addresses are invalid.
3. The `approve` wasn’t done correctly (it’s the airdrop contract that needs to be approved, not the initiator of the transaction).

You can narrow it down by removing the `require` and see if any drops are successful (the way you have it coded, one failure will roll back the entire transaction).